# Encryption with Crypto.js and cryptoswift generates different encryption cipher text

Tags: swift, encryption, aes, cryptojs, cbc-mode

I am trying to generate encrypted text in Node using Crypto.js using its AES algorithm. It works in Js for encryption and decryption both. Similarly I tried implementing same in Swift using CryptoSwift and it does encryption and decryption both in swift. But the problem arises when I want to use encrypted cipher text from JS to decrypt in Swift. The problem is that the encrypted text generated in JS is different from what is generated in Swift. The mode is CBC and padding is PKCS7.

**Swift Code**:

```
 func aes256CBC(key: String, input: String) -> String? {
    guard let keyData = key.data(using: .utf8), let inputData = input.data(using: .utf8) else {
        return nil
    }

    let salt = generateSalt(length: 8)
    let iv = generateSalt(length: 16)
    
    let key = try! PKCS5.PBKDF2(password: keyData.bytes, salt: salt.bytes, iterations: 1, keyLength: 32, variant: .md5).calculate()
        
    let aes = try! AES(key: key, blockMode: CBC(iv: iv.bytes), padding: .pkcs7)

    let encrypted = try! aes.encrypt(inputData.bytes)

    let result = Data(salt + iv + encrypted)

    return result.base64EncodedString()
}

func generateSalt(length: Int) -> Data {
    var salt = Data(count: length)
    let result = salt.withUnsafeMutableBytes {
        SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, length, $0.baseAddress!)
    }
    if result != errSecSuccess {
        fatalError("Failed to generate salt. SecRandomCopyBytes status: \(result)")
    }
    return salt
}
```

For checking, I am using [this site](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cryptojs-aes-encrypt-decrypt?file=index.js), as output generated by my js is same as this url generates.

`input = "test" key = "password"`

`JS Output: encryptedString = "U2FsdGVkX18087rLuHfWYc9JmmhZL4jJD/Pu8IGuL/E="`

`Swift Output: RtWc9mSXPY7/6A6x/9OTE7rhBJqEWxqEYkKe33VCpnesN1Q4wujpww==`

Comment: You are using a random IV / Salt, if you want the same outputs, you should probably use the same inputs (e.g. salt + iv) in addition to the text you wish to encrypt.

Comment: I don't know salt and iv used in cryptoJS. Can you guide me? I want same encryption and decryption as you can view on this site [Site](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cryptojs-aes-encrypt-decrypt?file=index.js)

Comment: If you are using `var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase");` it supposedly generates them for you. You could check this out : https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#custom-key-and-iv to provide your own.

Comment: Even with identical salt and IV, both codes would give different results because different logics are implemented: The key derivation functions differ (CryptoJS: `EVP_BytesToKey()`, CryptoSwift: PBKDF2), the IV handling differ and the encoding of the result. The fix is to change one of the codes so that both codes apply the same logic. Since PBKDF2 is more secure than the deprecated `EVP_BytesToKey()`, the CryptoJS code should be changed.

Comment: Is there any alternative instead of changing the code

Comment: If the goal is to decrypt the ciphertext gnerated by code A with code B, then of course not.

Comment: I tried but the encryptedText generated by swift is not decrypted by JS, I tried this by using CommonCrypto library but no success.

Comment: There is no problem at all to decrypt the ciphertext generated with the posted Swift code with CryptoJS, because CryptoJS supports PBKDF2. If you have problems, you need to post your CryptoJS code and describe the problem.